# Continuous random variable pdf question.

Tags: probability, continuity, random-variables

The continuous random variable X has pdf where

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}  \frac{25}{12(x+1)^2},\quad  & 0\le x\le 4 \\  0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

$E(X+1) = 1\frac23$ and $E(X) = 2/3$

1. Find the value of $c >0$ for which $P(X\le c) = c$

The answer should be $2/3$. I found $F(x) = -25/(12(x+1))$ by integration.

$$P(X\le c) = F(c) = -25/(12(c+1)) = c$$

Comment: No, you did not find $F(x)$ by _integration_; notice that its value is a negative number for all $x \in [0,4]$. Can you think of any reason why this is not right?

Comment: I am puzzled by what is called the density function. The parentheses make it look as if it is $\frac{25}{12(x+1)}$ on $[0,4]$ but that cannot be right.

Comment: Yes, more to @AndréNicolas's point - $$\int_0^4\frac1{x+1}\mathsf dx = \int_1^5\frac1 x\mathsf dx = \log 5.$$ So it should be something like $$f(x)=\frac{\log 5}{x+1}1_{[0,4]}(x).$$

Comment: I edited the formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Sorry, f(x) has (x+1)^2 in the denominator.

Comment: I think you do not want the $(x+1)^2$. Maybe $(x+1)^3$ was intended. Then an antiderivative is $-\frac{25}{24(1+x)^2)}$, and the integral from $0$ to $4$ is $1$, as it should be.

Comment: Yes, I just got 2/3 when I used (x+1)^3. There must have been a typing error in the original question. Also, E(X+1) works better by integrating f(x) = 25(x+1)/12(x+1)^3 for 0<x<4 to get 1 2/3, which is what I tried before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = \int_{t=0}^x f_X(t) \, dt = \int_{t=0}^x \frac{25}{12(t+1)^2} \, dt = \;?$$